# android bottom navbar shows text and background when clicked

Tags: java, android, navbar

As you can see in this gif:

[image]

when I click an icon on the navbar the icon and text background appear, also, if I long click it will appear a text too, how can I remove the icon and text background and the long click text?

Comment: How about `app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"`?

Comment: nope, I tried to put it inside the bottomview, the appbar and the bottomview style, but nothing, that background and that text still there